# Defining size of body with page ID

Tags: html, css

I've removed a widget `parallax-window` which seems to have been defining the size of my body, even though nothing was in the widget that I wanted to display.

Following this there doesn't appear to be any body at all,(the footer is resting right up against the head).

On desktop there's just blank white space, and that's how it should stay, with a small text widget in the middle (which isn't displaying, presumably because there's no body to display it. It doesn't seem to have effected anything below `768px`, perhaps because I have an image defining size there.

So I'd like to define the size of the body above `768px` myself.

It's the home page and the page ID is `28`.

Tried.

```
@media(min-width: 768px){body.page-id-28{width: 1400px; height: 700px;}}
```

It didn't work. Why not and what alternatives are there to defining the size of the body, (other than placing a widget on the homepage and then define the size of the widget or elements within the widget) ?

Desktop [here](https://4309.co.uk)

```
<body class="home page- 
template page-template- 
page- 
templates page-template- 
template-home page- 
template-page- 
templatestemplate-home-php 
page page-id-28 logged-in 
admin-bar no-customize- 
support wp-custom-logo 
cookies-set cookies- 
accepted has-sidebar- 
right">
<div id="page" 
class="site">
```

Comment: I don't know if is that the error but how you can see in develop mode you didin't close first rule css in your media query. [screen](https://ibb.co/tZwtn2p)

Comment: It's closed in my source code. Every media query with `body.page-id-28` is closed.

Comment: As you can see on my screen i going to your live website and you don't remember to close `width` with `;`

Comment: Ah, yes. Fixed that but didn't work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your code

```
@media(min-width: 768px){body.page-id-28 {width: 1400px !important height: 700px !important;}}
```

Need. Close width: 1440px ! important;

```
@media(min-width: 768px){body.page-id-28 {width: 1400px !important; height: 700px !important;}}
```

Comment: But my footer is still touching my header.

Comment: I'll try applying position:relative which may push footer content down

Comment: Nope. My footer is still at the top. Does that mean I'd have to move footer separately?